# Какой мак взять для нескольких сценариев разработки?

Tags: веб-программирование, mac

Учусь на программировании. Стал вопрос покупки нового пк, выбор пал на маки. Еще до конца не определился с направление в разработке, но это точно будет либо разработка на swift либо frontend. Сейчас выбираю между двумя маками, macbook pro 15 2015 (2.2Ghz, 16GB RAM, 256 SSD) и macbook pro 13 2017 (2.3Ghz, 16GB RAM, 256 SSD). Вопрос в том, будет ли большая разница в процессорах и будет ли она ощутима для моих задач, все-таки в 15-шке 4 ядра и 8 потоков, когда в 13-шке 2 ядра и 4 потока? Вроде, в маке 17 года 7 поколение процессора, а в маке 15 года 4.

Answer (score 0):

Если проблем с деньгами нет, то берите тот что более мощный , потому что разница в geekbench multi-core процессоров между ними почти 5,000 (9,500 и 14,500) 13шки и 15шки соответственно. Однако я не думаю, что это будет сильно ощущаться на производительности относительно ваших задач.

Answer (score 0):

Мак это немного необычный случай и разницы между этими двумя в процессе разработки не заметите. Максимум - возможно чуть дольше (порядка пары секунд разница) будет компилироваться проект на swift. Для фронта вообще большой мощности не надо по сути. Так что берите тот, который больше по деньгам подходит и больше нравится