# MAC для IOS Разработки

Tags: swift, mac, macbook

Кто пишет код на Swift, подскажите оптимальные параметры mac для комфортной работы. Не системные требования программ, а именно по вашему опыту использования. А так же imac или macbook.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1):

Я конечно не спец в таких вопросах, но тем не менее выскажу свое мнение :) Лично я считаю что чем круче спеки тем вам будет комфортнее. Есть у меня коллега - пишет приложение для iOS у него макбук прошка 13" с 128гб ссд и 8гб озу. Говорит что все круто и все летает. Я пробовал работать за макбуком 16" с 16гб озу и там тоже все летало. По поводу iMac ничего определенного сказать не могу, но думаю что разницы особой нету, за исключением того что с ноутбуком у вас будет больше мобильности чем со стационарным. Насколько я знаю из опыта общения с маковедами (не факт что они были правы) - распределение ресурсов в макоси немного другое чем в винде (с ней сравниваю потому что есть опыт). Например если вы будете делать что-то тяжелое в плане ресурсов на среднем/слабом ПК с виндой, то у вас вероятнее всего он довольно сильно будет тупить и виснуть. Если же вы будете делать такие же задачи на среднем макбуке например, то у вас фризы могут конечно появится но не так часто как на виндовском пк. У вас при покупке любой техники эпла будет ссд, озу и оптимизированная система. Лучше ориентироваться на линейку про, так как там самые топовые машинки продаются. Здесь вам конечно будут советовать разное, но я бы вам советовал основываться на своем бюджете. Единственное что могу сказать наверняка - берите лучшее что можете позволить, и оно будет на вырост, оно будет вас радовать и вы не скоро с него пересядете. Я уже много раз имел такой опыт - имел сумму на руках и мог купить топ ноут, как я считал, потом немного поискал + подкопил еще немного - купил намного круче чем мог купить при первом порыве. Советовать брать что-то определенное не могу, но могу дать совет - не спешите. К таким вопросам нужно подходить вдумчиво и рассудительно :) [Вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/787528/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%81%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8?rq=1) есть здесь подобный вопрос, может пригодится.

Comment: Mac mini еще есть, тоже хорошие машинки, в целом помимо ssd и оперативки имеет значение количество ядер процессора, так как благодаря этому икскод может компилировать сразу несколько файлов одновременно, что сильно ускоряет сборку

Comment: Да мини тоже норм, но его не упоминали в вопросе поэтому решил не писать)

Comment: У меня сейчас mini, но правда старенький и поэтому не поддерживает последнюю мак ось, но на нем по ощущениям 8 гб маловато.

Comment: что значит по ощущениям?)